# How do I display an entire object that matches my search by an attribute of that object in Python?

Tags: python, class, attributes

I am writing a program that keeps track of the animals on a farm and I want to be able to search for an animal by e.g: name, gender, age etc, which all are attributes to the objects. I am a complete noob when it comes to Python so all help is very appreciated.

Here is the code i have so far for this, but it only ads the attribute that is searched for to the list and then prints it. I want to be able to add the entire object to the list and print the whole object through that list.

```
class Djur:

    def __init__(self, art, namn, ålder, kön, gravid):
        self.art = art
        self.namn = namn
        self.age = ålder
        self.gender = kön
        self.gravid = gravid


    def __str__(self):
        return ("Art: " + str(self.art) + " " + "\n"
                "Namn: " + str(self.namn) + " " + "\n"
                "Ålder: " + str(self.age) + " " + "\n"
                "Kön: " + str(self.gender) + " " + "\n"
                "Gravid: " + str(self.gravid))
    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self)




try:

                val2 = input("Ange sök-text")

                l=[]

                for x in djurlista:
                    y = x.art or x.gender or x.namn or x.gravid or x.age
                    if y == val2:
                        l.append(x.art)
                        print(l)
                meny()


            except ValueError:
                print("Var god välj ett giltigt alternativ!")
```

Comment: I think you just need to wirte `l.append(x)`instead of `l.append(x.art)`.

Comment: I think @dome is correct. It's off-topic, but I doubt the `y = x.art or x.gender or x.namn or x.gravid or x.age` does what you want/need.

Comment: Thanks guys that solved it!! Been at this problem for several hours.

Comment: martineau could you explain what you mean by your comment, because i am not certain i fully understand my code.

Comment: I agree with @martineau. @Lanjen we mean that `or` operation is not doing what you wanted. I think that you are assaigning to `y` only the first value `x.art`and not the other ones.

Comment: Anyway, as I solved your problem, will you upvote and accept the answer if I post it?

Comment: Yes i tried it and it is as you say, but i found a way around it so now it is working!

Comment: I will accept your answer if I am allowed (new user so I can't do everything e.g upvote)

Comment: Lajen (and @dome): I meant that the result of the expression `x.art or x.gender or x.namn or x.gravid or x.age` will be the value of `art` whenever that attribute is not an empty string (or zero or some other value whose truthiness is considered `False` by Python), so that is what will probably get assigned to `y` most, if not all, of the time.

Comment: Ok, anyway you need 15 rep point to upvote but you can always accept answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a list with the objects you just need to write `l.append(x)` instead of `l.append(x.art)`. Now you are just appending the property `art`.